# terminating with uncaught exception NSException when calling addTarget

Tags: swift

I created a swift Playground and I want an action to happen whenever I press on a button, however I keep getting a runtime exception "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". How would I go about fixing this(swift) I am not sure what is going on, and I am new to swift. Thanks EDIT:  I added the full code

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit

let textFiled = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 320, y: 130, width: 100, height: 33))
let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1200, height: 1200))
var btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 280, y: 550, width: 200, height: 50))



public class LoadView: UIViewController {

public static func loadView() {


    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background1.png")!)

   //text label
    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 230, y: 100, width: 400, height: 30)
    label.text = "Enter a 3 Digit Key In the range 128-255:"
    label.textColor = .black

    //rectangle
    let rect = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 40, width: 718, height: 1100))
    rect.backgroundColor = .brown
    view1.addSubview(rect)

    //text field
    //let textFiled = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 320, y: 130, width: 100, height: 33))
    textFiled.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    textFiled.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.line
    view1.addSubview(textFiled)        

    //message text
    let msg2 = UILabel()
    msg2.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 400, width: 400, height: 30)
    msg2.text = "Encrypted Message:"
    msg2.textColor = .black

    //message text field
    let Encyped_msg = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 220, y: 435, width: 300, height: 33))
    Encyped_msg.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    Encyped_msg.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.line
    view1.addSubview(Encyped_msg)

   //message text
    let msg2 = UILabel()
    msg2.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 400, width: 400, height: 30)
    msg2.text = "Encrypted Message:"
    msg2.textColor = .black

    //message text field
    let Encyped_msg = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 220, y: 435, width: 300, height: 33))
    Encyped_msg.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    Encyped_msg.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.line
    view1.addSubview(Encyped_msg)

    view1.addSubview(msg)
    view1.addSubview(msg2)
    view1.addSubview(label)



    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view1


}


}


public class bttn: LoadView{
public static func createButton(){
    btn.setTitle("Process", for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    btn.backgroundColor = .green
    print("im here")
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bttn.encr), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    view1.addSubview(btn)
}

@objc func encr(sender: UIButton) {
    print("need to encrypt")
}

}
```

Comment: what are `msg` and `label` here?  `view1.addSubview(msg)` `view1.addSubview(msg2)`  `view1.addSubview(label)`

Comment: they are just UIlabels I put on the view, I excluded them to condense my code

Comment: Can you update your question with latest code you are using, then only we will be able to answer your question. Best if you can log the received error too..

Comment: I updated all the code that I am using, the only thing you can't see is that I call the function with LoadView.loadView()  and bttn.createButton() in another playground page, the only error message the console prints is "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"